# Order $4$ element of Tate-Shafarevich group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, tate-shafarevich-groups

Let $E/\Bbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\Bbb{Q}$. Tate-Shafarevich group $\mathit{Sha}(E/\Bbb{Q})$ is defined as follows.

$$\mathit{Sha}(E/\Bbb{Q})\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \operatorname{Ker}(H^1(G_ \Bbb{Q},E(\overline{\Bbb{Q}})) \to \prod_p {H^1(G_{\Bbb{Q}_p},E(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p}))$$

Elements of $\mathit{Sha}(E/\Bbb{Q})$ are torsos of $E$ which has rational points at every $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $\Bbb{R}$.

An example of order $2$ elements in $\mathit{Sha}(E/\Bbb{Q})$ is $[\text{smooth compactification of affine curve } 2y^2=x^4-17]\in \mathit{Sha}(E:y^2=x^3+17x/\Bbb{Q})$ (Lind).

An example of order $3$ elements in $\mathit{Sha}(E/\Bbb{Q})$ is $[3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0]\in \mathit{Sha}(E:x^3+y^3+60z^3=0/\Bbb{Q})$ (Selmer, 1961).

What is a known (typical) example of order $4$ elements in $\mathit{Sha}(E/\Bbb{Q})$ ?

Base on the period index argument, it should be a curve which does not have rational points on $\Bbb{Q}$ and its quadratic extension, but has rational points on degree $4$ extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ and has points locally at everywhere, but I cannot imagine such a curve.

Comment: 4-Selmer elements are given by pairs of $4 \times 4$ symmetric matrices, up to $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \times \text{GL}_4(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalence. To get a concrete example of an order 4 element in Sha, one just has to find a pair of such matrices which gives locally soluble curve that has no rational points.

Comment: Is it difficult (or any known result) to write down the  equation of the curve in $\Bbb{P}^n$ for small $n$ ? I think the process to find no rational points should take nontrivial arguments.